# how can i change this number into a sudoku grid format

Tags: python-3.x

i have a sudoku generator and the output is like this:

`800034065534267891100589304213000706456010000098640502900358000020476109687920050`

but i need it to be in this format:

```
my_sudoku =[
    [9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5],
    [0,0,3,6,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,7,0,0,9,0,2,0,0],
    [0,5,0,0,0,7,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,4,5,7,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,3,0],
    [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,6,8],
    [0,0,8,5,0,0,0,1,7],
    [7,9,0,8,1,3,4,5,2]]
```

i need something reverse of this:

```
def boardToCode(self, input_code=None): 
    if input_code:
        _board = ','.join([str(i) for j in input_code for i in j])
        return _board
    else:
        self.board = ','.join([str(i) for j in self.code for i in j])
        return self.board
```

but i cannot think of anything.

how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

this should do

```
board=[list(map(int, my_sudoku[i:i+9])) for i in range(0, 81, 9)]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```py
def code_to_board(code):
  nums = [int(i) for i in code]
  board = [nums[i:i + 9] for i in range(0, 81, 9)]
  return board
```

Comment: this produces something like this:
'''
[[0, 7, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4, 2, 5], [3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 8, 0, 7], [4, 9, 0, 7, 8, 5, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 7, 4, 0, 0, 5, 8, 3], [8, 3, 6, 5, 0, 7, 9, 4, 1], [5, 4, 9, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 0], [0, 6, 4, 1, 7, 2, 3, 0, 0], [2, 5, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 6, 0], [0, 8, 3, 0, 5, 0, 2, 1, 0]]
'''
i need them exactly like in my 1st post!

Comment: In the post you said you need it in a 2D array, which is what this function does. What's wrong with the output?

Comment: it is working ok, i thought i need 3D array but it is ok. a strange thing; the code is working since yesterday and still couldn't finish producing data. is this normal? (i am building 4x16 sudokus and solving them each with 12x10 methods, and omitting solves more than 2.5 seconds. So it means roughly 4.5 hours of work but it is still working since yesterday midday around 12:00.)